# jQuery - Working with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so I fixed my last error with the DIV and all..

OK so at the very top of my `javascript` file... I have

```
$(function() {
     var games = new Array(); // games array
});
```

and then in a new function I have: `var gamesLgth = games.length;`

but when I run it, I get this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: games is not defined`

When I weird because I initalized it at the very beginning...

Comment: "and then in a **new function** I have..." that is probably the issue; when you define a variable with `var`, it will only be available to the current function.

Comment: See this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851138/jquery-please-explain-to-me-closure-variable-context

Comment: Please show the code include new function.

Comment: See this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851138/jquery-please-explain-to-me-closure-variable-context

Comment: You can create a new array with just two characters: `var games = [];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`games` is out of scope. You need to store it somewhere such that your other function can access it.

For example, this will make your variable global.

```
var games;
$(function() {
    games = new Array(); // games array
});

$(function() {
   var gamesLgth = games.length;
   console.log(gamesLgth);
});
```

Comment: OF COURSE! I remember this in Java with global variables and such. It is coming back to me.! Thank you. I got it. I got it. Muchas gracias, senor.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring that variable within a `function` you have *scoped* the variable to that function, which means that that variable `games` is only available within that function.

```
$(function() {
     var games = new Array(); // games array

     ...


     var gamesLength = games.length; // works fine
});
```

But this following example will not:

```
$(function() {
     var games = new Array(); // games array
});

$(function() {
     var gamesLength = games.length; // won't work - im in a different scope
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized it as a local variable of a separate function. You need to make it global, or to pass it from function to function as argument to be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
var games = [];
```

instead of

```
var games = new Array();
```

and also be sure about the **games** scope.

Comment: Both are equivalent, but you're right on with the scope thing :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the games array to new again.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and write the code out for you:

```
var games;
$(function(){
   games = new Array();
   ...
});
$(function(){
  games.length; // Which would be zero
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized "games" in a function scope, it's not available outside the borders of $(function() {   ...  });